# How to get and parse .xlsx file in Azure Function called from Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I am working on a logic app that gets a file azure file file shares, adds them in azure blob storage and then calls a Azure Function that receives that blob (.xlsx file).

After the blob is created the Azure Function will parse the data in the blob and will insert the data in MS dynamics CRM entity.

My question is how can I access the blob in Azure Function and parse it so I can the data that will be store in the entity?

I have successfully created the logic app that performs the mentioned steps:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can connector in Azure logic app to insert data in Dynamics 365 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-crmonline

Comment: Hi @Rohan, the data is in the excel file. Does the logic app has any functionality where I can parse the data in the excel file and then insert it?

Comment: [RTM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob) on blob integration, use trigger to input as appropriate. Or if you're reading the contents yourself then use appropriate storage account SDK to read the file contents from blob storage.

Comment: @3iL - Check the following link if it helps. Provides information on connector  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-excel

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can I access the blob in Azure Function and parse
> it so I can the data that will be store in the entity?

From your screenshot, seems your logic app to trigger function is triggered by Http. So you can use azure function blob binding to access the blob in storage:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=csharp

(The information of blob name is incoming by json format, so binding can directly get the name.)

Regarding parsing, I think there are a lot of codes that can be used for reference. It is no need to be given here. If you need it, you can tell me(And please tell the language you are using.).